# Are tattoo inks vegan?

Tags: veganism

I asked [whether printer inks were vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/688/are-common-printer-ink-cartridges-vegan), but tattoo ones must be different since they are used on/in skin.

So, are tattoo inks vegan (not containing animal-related products)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tattoo inks may be vegan, but many are not. In addition, the standard transfer paper contains lanolin (wool fat), so that's not vegan either.

Here's a full explanation (edited) from [bitesize vegan website](http://bitesizevegan.com/vegan-lifestyle-2/are-tattoos-vegan-guide-to-a-vegan-tattoo/)

> Tattoo ink is formed of a pigment, which gives the ink its color,
>   suspended within a carrier solution.  The pigment is usually derived
>   from plants or metal.  Now, what my astute commenter was referring to
>   with the bone bit of his comment, however, is black ink, also called
>   “bone black” which can–but doesn’t always–contain charcoal and soot
>   derived from the charred bones of animals.
>
> Carrier solutions generally contain purified water, ethyl alcohol,
>   propylene glycol and glycerine and may also contain witch hazel.  For
>   vegans, it’s the glycerine we have to watch out for.  It can be from
>   either plants or from animal fats depending on the company.
>
> Aside from bone char pigment and glycerine carrier solutions, there
>   are other animal bits in tattoo inks to keep an eye out for.  Some
>   inks also use gelatin and shellac.
>
> Luckily there are plenty of vegan inks on the market, some of which
>   have the bonus of being non-toxic.
>
> Outside of the ink itself, other elements of the tattoo process can be
>   animal-laden.  Many artists use vaseline or petroleum jelly during
>   tattooing to help their tattoo machine glide more easily. petroleum
>   jelly itself can by and large be considered animal-free, although it’s
>   a byproduct of the oil industry, which is a bit concerning, and the
>   vaseline brand itself can contain bone char depending on the country
>   and definitely tests on animals.
>
> One lesser-known hidden animal product in the tattoo experience is the
>   lanolin in transfer paper, which comes from sheep’s wool. You see when
>   you get a tattoo, unless you have a badass free-hander, your artist
>   will draw the image out on what looks like tracing paper and apply it
>   to your glistening moist skin to leave an outline to follow.  This
>   allows you and your artist to work out ideal positioning and allows
>   you a bit of a preview.
>
> Luckily, there is a vegan transfer paper out there by Reprofx.

So, go to a tattoo place that explicitly advertises itself as vegan (and that you trust), if you are concerned about these things.